# Why anti ETag fingerprinting browser extensions won't work if I block images using other addons, like uBlock or uMatrix?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, privacy, privacy-extensions

I'm trying to use one of these Firefox extensions [suggested by ghacks](https://github.com/ghacksuserjs/ghacks-user.js/wiki/4.1-Extensions#small_orange_diamond-extensions-in-no-particular-order):

- [Header Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/header-editor/);
- [ETag Stoppa](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/etag-stoppa/).

As described by the wiki, this is what they do:

> Allows you to run Rules to modify headers such as blocking ETags

The problem is: these addons won't work if I block images in uMatrix, at all. Hence, I'd like to know why is that.

Also: do these addons work by preventing first-party image eTAGs or third-party as well?

**expected result**

- install ETag Stoppa;
- disable images globally for all parties (uMatrix);
- visit [Cookieless cookies](https://lucb1e.com/rp/cookielesscookies/);
- store message;
- clear cache;
- re-visit Cookieless cookies;
- **don't see** any previously storaged message.

**what's actually happening**

- install ETag Stoppa;
- enable images globally for all parties (uMatrix);
- visit Cookieless cookies;
- store message;
- clear cache;
- re-visit Cookieless cookies;
- **see** previously storaged message.

**disclaimer**

1. I'm cleaning browser cache by reopening it because I have prefs for it.

**links**

- [Cookieless cookies by lucb1e](https://lucb1e.com/rp/cookielesscookies/)

Comment: Could you try to explain what _won't work_ means? A reproducible sample test will help a lot. Tell us what you expected and what actually happened. Please note that you have to wipe your cache before etags works, cached etags will still be sent.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani done!

Comment: Ok. I suggest you try the extension `Etags Stoppa` **without** Umatrix, or even just by itself (just disable the uMatrix or the others for a while) and see if it works as expected. If it does work, then you should let the author know there is a conflict with your setup. If it doesn't, then Stoppa does not work for you.